# What application can I use to increase fan speed of MacBook Pro under Windows 7?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

On OS X Lion I use smcFanControl to increase fan speed. What application can I use on Windows 7 on MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Macs Fan Control](http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) does the job well. There are both Windows and Mac version available for free.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) with Windows running in a Bootcamp partitions to access temperature data and control the fan speeds on an iMac. He's very quick to turn around unsupported chipsets and the software tells you if you should report your chipset to the author for addition.

Comment: I can't increase fan speed. I go in Configure -> Fan, and see no fans listed

Comment: Report this to the SpeedFan dev and he can help you out with chipset support.

Comment: Done so, but no feedback. Lubbo's MacBook Pro Fan Control is turning my fans to max rpm and shows 90 C for GPU#2 temperature.